# What happens if i set 'raspicam_node/image' queue size to 1?

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, ros

I can't get real-time image from raspberry pi cam.
So I adjusted the Queue Size from 100 to 1.

Then there was an improvement in performance.

I wonder why there was a performance improvement.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   ros::init(argc, argv, "lane_driving");
   ros::NodeHandle nh, nhp;
   image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);


   pub = nhp.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/cmd_vel", 100);
   subAD = nh.subscribe("arrowDetecter", 1,&arrowMessage);
   subScan = nh.subscribe("/scan",1,&scanMsgCallback);
   subOdom = nh.subscribe("/odom", 1,&odomMsgCallback);
   image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("/raspicam_node/image", 1, &poseMessageReceived, ros::VoidPtr(), image_transport::TransportHints("compressed"));


  while(ros::ok()){
    baseCmd.linear.x = 0.01;
    pub.publish(baseCmd);
     ros::spin();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of messages that arrive on the `/raspicam_node/image` topics in a single `ros::spin()` is greater than the `queue_size`, the extra messages will be discarded. What this means is that your callback is probably not running for every image that comes from your camera. So you are probably "dropping" (not analyzing) some of the camera frames. This would give the performance improvement you observed.

Whether or not this is what you want depends on your application.